# How can I use automapper to map 2 enums that use different casing

Tags: enums, automapper, case-insensitive

I have many enums that I want to keep all caps that I have to map to another system that has no standard at all (caps, no caps, pascal, camel). I can't find an automapper flag to tell it to ignore case for enums. I could use a custome converter for each enum but I would prefer a generic converter since there are so many.

Some answers here have implied that automapper does this already. I don't get that from my testing.

If I have these enums:

```
public enum AllCaps
{
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
}

public enum NoCaps
{
    value1,
    value2,
    value3
}

public enum MixedCaps
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}
```

These maps:

```
CreateMap<AllCaps, NoCaps>();
CreateMap<AllCaps, MixedCaps>();
CreateMap<NoCaps, AllCaps>();
CreateMap<NoCaps, MixedCaps>();
CreateMap<MixedCaps, AllCaps>();
CreateMap<MixedCaps, NoCaps>();
```

This code:

```
var vAllCaps = new AllCaps();
var vNoCaps = new NoCaps();
var vMixedCaps = new MixedCaps();

vAllCaps = AllCaps.VALUE2;
vNoCaps = NoCaps.value2;
vMixedCaps = MixedCaps.Value2;

var AllCapsToNoCaps = Mapper.Map<AllCaps, NoCaps>(vAllCaps);
var AllCapsToMixedCaps = Mapper.Map<AllCaps, MixedCaps>(vAllCaps);
var NoCapsToAllCaps = Mapper.Map<NoCaps, AllCaps>(vNoCaps);
var NoCapsToMixedCaps = Mapper.Map<NoCaps, MixedCaps>(vNoCaps);
var MixedCapsToAllCaps = Mapper.Map<MixedCaps, AllCaps>(vMixedCaps);
var MixedCapsToNoCaps = Mapper.Map<MixedCaps, NoCaps>(vMixedCaps);
```

The result of all my mapped variables are either VALUE1, value1, or Value1 and not the expected VALUE2, value2, or Value2.

Comment: Remove the CreateMap calls.

Comment: I had tried with or without the CreateMap calls. I tried it without again and I get the same results,

Comment: It works for me. Try upgrading.

Comment: You're saying that with your version of Automapper that the case of the enums doesn't matter and you get the desired results? Which version is this?

Comment: The latest, 8.0.

Comment: We are already on 8.0. We are using it in a .Net Core app. You get values of VALUE2, value2, and Value2 when you do it?

Comment: Yes, on the full framework. Being on .Net Core is essential info you didn't even mention.

Comment: But it works on .Net Core too.

Comment: Does not work for me
AutoMapper 10.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Automapper does a case insensitive mapping between enumerations automatically.
No `CreateMap<EnumSource, EnumDest>()` call for an enum is required.

There are some details worth mentioning:

- Enum values embedded inside a mapped type are case insensitive mapped
- `configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` Does not check if a target value is available for all source values
- **If a source value does not exist in the target enumeration, the numeric value is taken**

The [AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping) can validate the enumeration mappings, but this extension does a case sensitive check. And it is not really required for a simple enum to enum mapping.

A custom validation can be added to check valid enum mappings

Example Code:

```
config.Advanced.Validator(context =>
            {
                if (context.TypeMap != null)
                {
                    foreach (var memberMap in context.TypeMap.MemberMaps)
                    {
                        if (memberMap.SourceType.IsEnum && memberMap.DestinationType.IsEnum)
                        {
                            var hasMappingError = false;
                            var sourceEnumValue = Enum.GetValues(memberMap.SourceType).Cast<object>()
                                .Select(x => x.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
                            var targetEnumValues = Enum.GetValues(memberMap.DestinationType).Cast<object>()
                                .Select(x => x.ToString().ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();

                            var messageBuilder =
                                new StringBuilder(
                                    $"Missing enum mapping from {memberMap.SourceType.FullName} to {memberMap.DestinationType.FullName}");

                            messageBuilder.AppendLine();
                            messageBuilder.AppendLine("The following source values are not mapped:");

                            foreach (var sourceValue in sourceEnumValue)
                            {
                                if (!targetEnumValues.Contains(sourceValue))
                                {
                                    hasMappingError = true;
                                    messageBuilder.AppendLine($" - {sourceValue}");
                                }
                            }

                            if (hasMappingError)
                            {
                                throw new AutoMapperConfigurationException(messageBuilder.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I get the same result by default, without any map.

Comment: @  Lucian Bargaoanu 
Does the configuration validation still check that all source enum values are mapped without a map?

Comment: No, you misunderstand. If you remove _all_ your code you get the same exact effect. So I see no reason why you would write code that does nothing. I don't see how validation applies to enums.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have updated my use case, and I hope this shows why validation applies to enums

Comment: `Map<Dest>(Source.Value1)` is in fact `Dest.VALUE1`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Yes of course if you know the value at the time you write the code, then you can replace the mapping with the target value.. But a mapper is to map a value at runtime to another value.

Comment: You misunderstood. AM doesn't map by values by default. That's just wrong!

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu You are right. Without any 'special code" from  AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping it uses case insensitive name matching. Unfortunately with this Approach there is no validation. If there is a value in the source enum without counterpart in the target enumeration, then the numeric value is taken. The "AutoMapper.Extensions.EnumMapping" did a correct validation in this case.
Thanks for your hints

Comment: If you want to change your answer to smth like this comment, I'll remove the down-vote. Note that you don't _really_ need that package, you can add custom validations through an extension point. See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/7a00700de61cd3234b6a6eb4bf0f6bbe402369b1/src/UnitTests/ConfigurationValidation.cs#L30). But I see your point.

Comment: That code can be simplified. Just check that `context.Mapper is EnumToEnumMapper` instead. That ensures you're exactly in the relevant case. And then add your validation.